# OmniFaces Json#encode() stack overflow with IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke getter of property 'classes' of bean 'class java.lang.Class'

Tags: json, jsf, stack-overflow, omnifaces

I am experiencing a stackoverflow exception doing exactly as explained in the documentation ([here](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.4/org/omnifaces/cdi/push/Socket.html#channels))

The error occurs when sending anything other than a String (ie a bean, or HashMap).

```
@Push
@Inject
private PushContext console;

void onEvent(@Observes ApplicationEvent event) {

    final Map<String, Object> dto = new HashMap<>();
    dto.put("timestamp", event.getTimestamp());
    dto.put("message", event.getMessage());
    dto.put("severity", event.getSeverity());
    console.send(dto); 

    // console.send(event); This line does not work
    // console.send(event.getMessage()); This line works
}
```

.

***Stack trace***

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke getter of property 'classes' of bean 'class java.lang.Class'.
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:178)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:191)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeArray(Json.java:123)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:83)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:191)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:191)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeArray(Json.java:123)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:83)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:191)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:191)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeBean(Json.java:191)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encode(Json.java:89)
at org.omnifaces.util.Json.encodeArray(Json.java:123)
// Repeats to infinity & beyond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will indeed fail that way when one of map/bean properties is a `Class` object whose `classes` property in turn references itself. Perhaps it's the `severity`?

I have as per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/d5395051c8563859bba7b06ad80205cf70f88ed4) improved `Json#encode()` to just print `Class#getName()` when a `Class` instance is encountered instead of handling it as a bean. The fix is available as per OmniFaces 2.5.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the code to send a String instead of an enum.